# How to format specific entries in a table?

Tags: r

My first column of a table contains some names. Defined by a vector. I need to show the output table and highlight (e.g. using bold characters or a different color) specific names. The names to be highlighted are defined in a different vector.

Here is my code:

''' r

````
df<-cbind(1:5,6:10,11:15)
df<-as.data.frame(df)
Risk<-c("Equity","FX","IR","Issuer","Credit") # first column in the table
df<-cbind(Risk,df)# final table
hnames<-c("FX","IR") # names to be highlighted in the first column of the
                     # table
```
````

In summary I want to highlight the common elements between the 'Risk' and 'hnames' vectors. Thank you in advance for your replies.

Comment: what have been your attempts to solve this? How about trying the [flextable](https://davidgohel.github.io/flextable/) package?

Answer (score 0):

Try using formattable

```r
formattable(df, list(
     Risk= formatter("span",style = ~ style(color=ifelse(Risk %in% hnames, "grey", NA), font.weight = ifelse(Risk %in% hnames, "bold", NA)))))
```